# Console.log in Dart Language

Tags: console, dart

How can I log into the browser console, like `console.log` in JavaScript, from the Dart language?

Comment: You can also try packages like logging or scribe https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/logging https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/scribe

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Simple:

```
print('This will be logged to the console in the browser.');
```

A basic top-level `print` function is always available in all implementations of Dart (browser, VM, etc.). Because Dart has string interpolation, it's easy to use that to print useful stuff too:

```
var a = 123;
var b = Point(2, 3);
print('a is $a, b is ${b.x}, ${b.y}');
```

Answer (score 65):

Also, `dart:html` allows use of `window.console` object.

```
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  window.console.debug("debug message");
  window.console.info("info message");
  window.console.error("error message");
}
```

Comment: This seems work in firefox, at least i tested window.console.debug('')

Comment: This answer is much better, because you can traverse object graphs in the console just as you can do it with any JS library. Does work in current FF.

Comment: in combination with Flutter you will get for the import: _Avoid using web-only libraries outside Flutter web plugin packages_

Answer (score 10):

It’s easy! Just import the logging package:

```
import 'package:logging/logging.dart';
```

Create a logger object:

```
final _logger = Logger('YourClassName');
```

Then in your code when you need to log something:

```
_logger.info('Request received!');
```

If you catch an exception you can log it and the stacktrace as well.

```
_logger.severe('Oops, an error occurred', err, stacktrace);
```

Logging package documentation : https://github.com/dart-lang/logging

Comment: this is a dependency, needs to be added to pubspec.yml
dependencies:
  logging: ^0.11.4

Comment: You also have to add some code to make the Logger do something useful. If you only have the code above, the log messages will be sent into the void. To direct log messages to the console, for instance, you can use code like this:

`// Configure logging to output to console:
Logger.root.level = Level.ALL;
Logger.root.onRecord.listen((record) {
  print('${record.level.name}: ${record.time}: ${record.message}');
});`

Comment: This does not answer the question of "writing to the console". Doing just what you said doest nothing unless you register a logger that writes to the console... And then you're back at square one of trying to find a way to write to the console.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Dart's built-in `log()` function

```
import 'dart:developer';

log('data: $data');
```

You can also use `print()`, but this is not a good practice because it can slow down your program in a production environment. `debugPrint`, `log` and other methods will prevent this.

Comment: this is the answer that im looking for, thanks mate

Answer (score 2):

Simple:
`print("hello word");`
or
`debugPrint(" hello word);`

Comment: debugPrint requires import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

Answer (score 0):

When you use only Dart without Flutter, then this is a good and easy solution:

```dart
void log(var logstr) {
  stdout.writeln("-> " + logstr.toString());
}
```